# How to split a Service class in two but still use them like one?

Tags: php, class-design, functions, methods

I've got a class:

`AuthenticationService`

- `findLoggedInUser()`

  Checks session if User is logged in. If not, check client persistent user login cookie and log in.
- `loginUser($email, $pw, $remember = false)`

  Log User in, and if `$remember` is true create persistent login cookie for User and a record for it in the database.
- `logoutUser()`

  Removes User from the session, and any User persistent login cookie from the client and corresponding record in the database.

And I figured that I should separate this class into two different classes; one that handles the session part and one for the cookie part. So I would pretty much end up with two classes with more or less the same methods, but taking care of a different responsibility.

What would be the best way to combine those together, as if I would have a single `AuthenticationService` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the level of abstraction.

A developer who uses `AuthenticationService` class doesn't care if, under the hood, the class is using cookies, session, database or some magical parameters within an URI. It makes sense to have both `findLoggedInUser()` and `loginUser()` in the same class.

The class itself, on the other hand, relies on a lower abstraction: it may know whether it should use cookies or session, but doesn't care about the actual underlying mechanism (such as how sessions are handled: all that matters is to be able to get and set session variables).

This means that you can keep `AuthenticationService` and create two additional classes:

1. `class`**`AuthenticationCookieHandler`**

   - `void CreateCookie(User user)`
   - `UserId FindUser()`
2. `class`**`Session`**

   - `bool IsAuthenticated()`
   - `User FindCurrentUser()`
   - `void AssignUser(User user)`
   - `void Reset()`

Comment: So I would have an `AuthenticationService` which has `AuthenticationCookieHandler` and `AuthenticationSessionHandler` as it's dependencies?

Comment: @KidDiamond: exactly.